# Unable to migrate stored procedure from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure-sql-database

I am trying to migrate a database from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Azure. I have successfully migrated my tables and views by generating scripts from my SQL Server 2008 instance.

However, I am now trying to migrate my stored procedures. There is one specific procedure that is giving me an error. The error says:

> Msg 7601, Level 16, State 2, Procedure MyStoredProcedure, Line 10
>   Cannot use a CONTAINS or FREETEXT predicate on table or indexed view 'MyTable' because it is not full-text indexed.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how to fix this in SQL Azure. Can somebody please tell me how to get this resolved?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you moved your tables in Azure the text search feature was disabled.
The problem here is that it's not supported yet.

So to fix the problem you must remove the text search reference (ex:`CONTAINS` or `FREETEXT`) in your stored procedures.

A probably good alternative is to use Lucene.Net and move the data in Blob storage. Move detail here: [implement-search-in-azure-sql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9131602/implement-search-in-azure-sql)

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Lucene.Net is a much better free text search than SQLServer has anyway.